# samba security share && user

Tags: samba, file-server

This is my smb.conf:

```
[global]
workgroup = myworkgroup
netbios name = mercurio
server string = fileServer
security = share
map to guest = Bad User

[Share]
comment = Carella di condivisione globale
path = /home/share
guest ok = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Everyone has r/w access to this folder and it is ok.
Now I need to share another folder but with only some users. I think I must change security options but it is in the global section!

there are some other problem. here the config:

```
[secure folde]
comment = Secure folder
path = /home/secure
valid users = ignazioc
```

but from my mac i see this message http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31437518/Screen%20Shot%202012-02-10%20at%2015.50.15.png
(file not found)
and this is the folder

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 ignazioc ignazioc  4096 Feb 10 09:39 secure/
```

Comment: you can add `valid users = <usernamelist>` by putting below the path of the folder you want to share. you can also add invalid users's list by `invalid users=<usernamelist>`

Comment: if you are using selinux try `setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on` for using home folders. which os you are using??

Comment: i edited my original post. i'm using debian 6 and smbd 3.5.6

Comment: please post you log file it will be stored in the name of `samba.<ip of computer you are using(windows/mac)>.log` and check whether you `ignazioc` is in smbusers or not otherwise try this `smbpasswd -a smbuser`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this configuration:

```
[global]
   # allow hosts = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24
    workgroup = debianizzati
    server string = server@debianizzati.org
    security = user
    guest account = ospite
    map to guest = Bad User
    #username map = /etc/samba/utenti.map
    netbios name = debianizzati
    #netbios aliases = alias1 ... aliasN
    #include = /etc/samba/smb.conf.%L

    #passwd program = /bin/passwd %u
    #pam password change = yes
    #obey pam restrictions = yes
    #passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuc$
    #unix password sync = Yes

[condivisione]
path = /home/utente1
        valid users = utente1
        read only = no
        guest ok = no

[condivisione 2]
path = /home/share
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```